# css classes appears but style not applied -REACTSTRAP - CSS MODULES

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, reactstrap

I created an application using create-react-app. I am using CSS modules by configuring webpack files. when I use reactstrap Bootstrap classes appears but styling not applying.

Following instructions from https://reactstrap.github.io/

imported CSS in an index.js file too, But style not applying.

```
 {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
      },
```

I tried  import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/778

But it throws an error.'unexpected symbol !'

[image]

Comment: could you please check with `test:/\.(s*)css$/,` ?

Comment: I tried It is not working... i update question with screenshot. @lsa4299

Comment: refer this link, looks very easy -> https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-use-webpack-with-react-and-bootstrap-b94d33765970

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Import Bootstrap CSS in the src/index.js file: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem by using Bootstrap CSS as CDN.